# How to List Specification Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote a view. Example of view you can see under the code.
I am writing a script for the list data.
Example of view:

```
DONEM_ID, URUN_ID, TARIFF, TARIFE_PRI, START_DATE, END_DATE
xx10      1         12      123        01-02-2003  null
xx11      1         12      123        01-02-2003  01-11-2003
xx12      1         12      124        01-11-2003  null
```

I wanna list

```
URUN_ID, TARIFF, TARIFE_PRI, START_DATE, END_DATE
1         12      123        01-02-2003  01-11-2003
1         12      124        01-11-2003  null
```

How can i list this?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation usually helps (code you might need begins at line #8):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm-dd-yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with
  2  -- sample data; you have that, don't type it
  3  test (donem_id, urun_id, tariff, tarife_pri, start_date, end_date) as
  4    (select 'xx10', 1, 12, 123, date '2003-01-02', null              from dual union all
  5     select 'xx11', 1, 12, 123, date '2003-01-02', date '2003-01-11' from dual union all
  6     select 'xx12', 1, 12, 124, date '2003-01-11', null              from dual
  7    )
  8  select urun_id, tariff, tarife_pri, min(start_date) start_date, max(end_date) end_date
  9  from test
 10  group by urun_id, tariff, tarife_pri
 11  order by urun_id, tariff, tarife_pri;

   URUN_ID     TARIFF TARIFE_PRI START_DATE END_DATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         12        123 01-02-2003 01-11-2003
         1         12        124 01-11-2003

SQL>
```